# jQuery $.get() Array Returns [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

**test.php** includes this:

```
echo json_encode( array(
  array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm"),
  array("name"=>"2","time"=>"1242pm"),
  array("name"=>"J231ohn","time"=>"2p213m"),
));
```

**jQuery**:

```
$.get("test.php", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(n, val) {
    alert(n + ': ' + val)
  });
}, "json");
```

This is the **result**:

```
0: [object Object]
1: [object Object]
2: [object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: related: [Javascript - \[object Object\] means?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8892465/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
alert(n + ': name = ' + val.name + ' time = ' + val.time);
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know php but my guess is you need to do this instead, as each val is a json object.

```
$.get("test.php", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(n, val) {
    alert(n + ': ' + val.name + ' ' + val.time)
  });
}, "json");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/uLGSh/) example

Answer (score 2):

Use console.log(data) to get a decent look at what's inside your JSON from the console in Firebug or Webkit.

Great tutorial here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/debugging-tools/

Answer (score 1):

Technically, nothing.  'val' references the object, which I suspect isn't what you want.  You probably want the values stored in each array.  So, instead of alerting out 'val', you probably want to access the array key values:

```
alert(n + ': ' + val.name + ' ' + val.time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .getJSON. Try:

```
$.getJSON("test.php", function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(n, val) {
         alert(n + ': ' + val)
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on your browser, you could call `val.toSource()` which will spill the objects contents instead of its type (which is the default behaviour for .toString() )

a nice, shorthand way to write this is `alert ([n, val.toSource() ]);`