# What does [object Object] mean? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of my alerts is giving the following result:

```
[object Object]
```

What does this mean exactly? (This was an alert of some jQuery object.)

Comment: See also [what does \[object Object\] mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750225/1048572)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It means you are alerting an instance of an object. When `alert`ing the object, `toString()` is called on the object, and the default implementation returns `[object Object]`.

```
var objA = {};
var objB = new Object;
var objC = {};

objC.toString = function () { return "objC" };

alert(objA); // [object Object]
alert(objB); // [object Object]
alert(objC); // objC
```

If you want to inspect the object, you should either `console.log` it, `JSON.stringify()` it, or enumerate over it's properties and inspect them individually using `for in`.

Comment: [Read this article for better understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean/57310111#57310111)

Answer (score 21):

As @Matt already explained the reason for `[object object]`, I would like to elaborate on how to inspect the object's value. There are three options that come to my mind:

- `JSON.stringify(JSONobject)`
- `console.log(JSONobject)`
- or iterate over the object

Basic example.

```
var jsonObj={
    property1 : "one",
    property2 : "two",
    property3 : "three",
    property4 : "fourth",
};

var strBuilder = [];
for(key in jsonObj) {
  if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    strBuilder.push("Key is " + key + ", value is " + jsonObj[key] + "\n");
  }
}

alert(strBuilder.join(""));
// or console.log(strBuilder.join(""))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b1u6hfns/

Answer (score 10):

The alert() function can't output an object in a read-friendly manner. Try using console.log(object) instead, and fire up your browser's console to debug.

Answer (score 3):

If you are popping it in the DOM then try wrapping it in

```
<pre>
    <code>{JSON.stringify(REPLACE_WITH_OBJECT, null, 4)}</code>
</pre>
```

makes a little easier to visually parse.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `JSON.stringify(obj)`

For example:

```
exampleObj = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3};
alert(JSON.stringify(exampleObj))
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was getting [Object, Object] because I was doing

```
console.log("particular_object" + particular_object)
```

Instead of

```
console.log("particular_object")
console.log(particular_object)
```

I guess adding another string in the same console.log of an object prevents the object from loading..

But most cases you just have to do:

```
JSON.stringify(particular_object))
```

UPDATE:
Cool comment/clarification by @stevejboyer below!

If you are getting this error from passing text plus an object in the same console.log method by using a plus sign(+); You can actually use a comma to avoid any errors and still console text along with your object.

By doing this instead:

```
console.log("particular_object", particular_object)
```

Comment: Note that you can write `console.log('particular object', particular_object)` to consolidate the two console.log calls to one line

Comment: @stevejboyer Oh wow, that's pretty cool you can use a comma instead. I added the note to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got `[object Objects]` when I did the following:

```
const person2 = {
    name: "Jo",
    age: 27,
    address: {
        city: "Some city",
        state: "Some state"
    }
}

const requestedPerson = person2

const { 
    name,
    age, 
    address, 
    favFood = "Not defined"
} = requestedPerson

console.log(`Address: ${address}`);
```

And it was the same as using:

```
console.log("Address: " + address)
```

**Solution:** I got it to work by simply using a comma:

```
console.log("Address:", address)
```

Answer (score -1):

Alerts aren't the best for displaying objects. Try console.log? If you still see Object Object in the console, use JSON.parse like this > `var obj = JSON.parse(yourObject); console.log(obj)`

Comment: No, `JSON.parse` does not help.

Comment: you probably meant ’JSON.stringify’ instead