# $.post returns [object Object]

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Why this returns `[object Object]` ??? I want to return `#new` content in to a alert. (actually i want to append that text to a new div, I can do that if this `[object Object]` problem resolved)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post("post.php", {"test": "hello"}, function(data) {
           var myDiv = $(data).filter("#new");
           alert(myDiv);
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Because it is an object, try `console.dir` to see what properties it has

Comment: because it s jQuery object now as you used $(data) even there aren't any response. try $(data).filter("#new").html();

Comment: `console.log` says still it includes all texts in that `post.php` page. `<div id="new">NEW</div><div id="next">NEXT</div>`

Comment: what do you want to see.

Comment: related: [Javascript - \[object Object\] means?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8892465/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because myDiv is object you have to access html in it,

use `html()` function of jquery if you want html,
use `text()` function of jquery if you want text instead of html

```
 myDiv.html();

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("post.php", {"test": "hello"}, function(data) {
       var myDiv = $(data).filter("#new");
       alert(myDiv.html());
    });
  });
```

Comment: COOl. What a simple question that i asked nha... :)

Answer (score 3):

It works perfectly fine.

`alert` does **not** show all the properties of an object, which is what you are trying to alert.
Try using the `console` for that:

```
//info on the jQuery DOM obj:
console.log(myDiv);

//info on the jQuery obj:
console.dir(myDiv);
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/agNNW/ (Thanks [@Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669932/post-returns-object-object/11669982#comment15467703_11669982))

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say it is working perfectly. If your `myDiv` is a DOM element, that is an object and `alert` has no idea how to print it. Never rely on alert for debugging purposes. Try appending it to a DOM element and it will probably work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like many jQuery methods, `.filter()` returns a jQuery object, so your current alert is quite correctly showing `[object Object]`.

Assuming `data` is a string of html, you can see the contents of the `#new` element within that html by doing this:

```
var myDiv = $(data).filter("#new");
alert(myDiv.html());
// or
alert(myDiv.text());
// or put the text in a variable:
var newText = myDiv.html();
// or
var newText = $(data).filter("#new").html();
```

To append to your other element:

```
$("#someotherelement").append(myDiv.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

myDiv will contain a jQuery object, so if you want to see its' contents, you shoud use

```
alert(myDiv.text());
```

or

```
alert(myDiv.html());
```

or

```
console.log(myDiv);
```