# this Javascript code gives output as [object, Object] , instead of [f, dog]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, angularjs-filter

this Javascript code gives output as [object, Object] , instead of [f, dog].??

```
 <html>
     <body>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
       <script>
        var animals = [{name:'f', species :'dog'},{name:'f1', species :'dog1'}];
        function isSog(animal) {

            if(animal.species==='dog') return animal;
        }
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = animals.filter(isSog);
        }
       </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - \[object Object\] means?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892465/javascript-object-object-means)

Comment: You have a typo isSog, probably you meant isDog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert array that you get (after `filter` method) into string before assigning to innerHTML. So as an example below I am calling `JSON.stringify`.

You can do :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(animals.filter(isSog));
```

Or you can choose any other format you want. You will have to do some further processing on returned array.

For a simple case such as yours, you can do following:

```js
var animals = [{
  name: 'f',
  species: 'dog'
}, {
  name: 'f1',
  species: 'dog1'
}];

function isSog(animal) {

  if (animal.species === 'dog') return animal;
}

var retObj = animals.filter(isSog);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "[" + retObj[0].name + "," + retObj[0].species + "]";
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Note that if your returned array is larger, looping and creating a string would be right option.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you try to output an object as a string. And it hasn't user-defined `toString()` method and falls back to the default one that gives you `[object Object]`. You could add that method like this in order to do something useful, for example, it could return animal's name:

```js
     var animals = [{name:'f', species :'dog', toString: function() {
       return this.name}
    }, {name:'f1', species :'dog1', toString: function() {
       return this.name}
    }];
   
    function isSog(animal) {
        if(animal.species==='dog') return animal;
    }
    console.log('' + animals.filter(isSog)); // forcing string conversion as you do in your code
```

Answer (score 0):

.filter returns a new array. You can't output reference types like this. You need to specify what you want to output from them to the DOM. In you case:

```
var newArr = animals.filter(isSog);
var str = '';
if(newArr.length > 0){
    for(var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
        str += "[" + newArr.name + ", " + newArr.species + "] <br>"
    }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the array that is being returned from the `filter` method is an object. When you display that object in your HTML it is converted to a string. If you run the method `animals.toString()` you'll see what I mean. So if you want to display your intended result you'll have a construct a string on your own that looks like the way you want it or you can use `JSON.stringify` to convert the array to String.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isSog(animal) {

            if(animal.species==='dog') return animal;
        }
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = animals.filter(isSog);
        }
```

The isSog function returns the object animal. That is the reason why you get the result [object, Object].

```
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(animals.filter(isSog));
        }
```

Hope this helps