# Why js variable show [object object] but console.log() works?

Tags: javascript

I have some codes

```
var weibo = { weibo: { url: '//testurl.com', icon: 'fa fa-weibo' } }
var mail = { mail: { url: '//testurl.com', icon: 'fa fa-envelope' } }
var github = { github: { url: '//testurl.com', icon: 'fa fa-github' } }

var [key] = Object.keys(weibo)
var name = weibo[key]
console.log(weibo[key])
```

I want to get object from `weibo` and store into name variable

But name show `[object object]`

[image]

I am not use `alert` from [What does [object Object] mean? (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892465/what-does-object-object-mean-javascript)

`key` is a string `weibo`
[image]

I just want to store variable into name, why `chrome dev tools` show `[object object]`?

`console.log()` works, it show corrent object info
[image]

**Update please see my gif**

[image]

---

Comment: Don't use square brackets around `key` variable when you're defining it!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the bracket notation. Why this should cause the problem?

Comment: The code seems to be fine, and does work (https://codesandbox.io/s/3y8lmj3q8m). What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: @phpcoderx I use `Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, I also think it should works, It's a bug or not? I copy your codes and run in my chrome dev snippet, but first console.log() show [object object], But when I open my dev tools, your codes have correct logs in my console

Comment: @FZs Why? it's  `array destructuring`. I think it same as `var key = Object.keys(weibo)[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now you will probably never ever use global variables anymore :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This had me thinking for a while, turns out there is a `window.name` global variable defined in browsers ([MDN:Window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)).

According to MDN:
***window.name will convert all values to their string representations by
using the toString method.***

When `toString` is applied to an object, the output will be `[object object]`.

So either enclose your piece of code within its own scope (probably inside a function) or rename your `name` variable.

Comment: Yes! you are right! you must be an great developer! It works now when I enclosure using `(function(){})()`, This question will remind me of global scope variable

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var key = Object.keys(weibo)
var name = key[0]
```

Comment: I want to know why `var name=weibo[key]` not equal to `console.log(weibo[key)`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have created "weibo" as an object, and you passing this to a primitive data type reference " name ".

Comment: key is `"weibo"`, So I think weibo[key] === weibo["weibo"], but from dev tools, name show as `[object object]`