# Autocomplete from selected data in combobox : jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to make autocomplote for my form, the data was from selected combobox.

Heres my controller :

```
public function cari(){
    $kode_list=$this->request->getVar('list_produksi_toko');
    //$kode_list=$_GET['kode_list'];
    $cari['hasil'] =$this->produksiModel->mencari($kode_list);
    echo json_encode($cari);
}
```

model :

```
public function mencari($keyword)
{
    //$query= $this->builder()->getWhere('list_produksi_toko',array('kode_list'=>$id));
    $query = $this->groupBy('kode_list')->like('kode_list', $keyword)->findAll();
    return $query;
}
```

and javascript in my view :

```
<script>

          $('#produk').change(function(){
            var list_produksi_toko = $(this).val();

            
            $.ajax({
             url:"/Produksi/cari",
             method: 'post',
             data:{list_produksi_toko: list_produksi_toko},
             success:function(data){
              jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               // var ddas = data.buyer
                alert (data);
                $.each(data, function(key, val){ 
                $('#buyer').val('<value="'+data['buyer']+'">');
                 // document.getElementById('nama_barang').value=val.nama_barang;
                 // document.getElementById('jenis_kain').value=val.jenis_kain;
                 // document.getElementById('warna').value=val.warna;
                 // document.getElementById('pcs').value=val.pcs;
               });
              }
            })
          });
          //   $.ajax({
          //     url: '/ProduksiModel/getProduksi',
          //     data:"produk="+produk ,
          //   }).success(function (data) {
          //     var json = data,
          //     obj = JSON.parse(json);
          //     $('#buyer').val(obj.nama);
          //     $('#status_order').val(obj.status_order);
          //     $('#nama_barang').val(obj.nama_barang);
          //     $('#jenis_kain').val(obj.jenis_kain);
          //     $('#warna').val(obj.warna);
          //     $('#pcs').val(obj.pcs);
          //   });
          // }
        </script>
```

I have a problem to show each data to each form, with this code it show error in the console like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"hasil":[{"kode_list":"LPT20060001","tanggal":"2020-06-08","status_order":"Full order","buyer":"IK001,Ik Collection","nama_barang":"IK05900,Renata Blouse","jenis_kain":"Mosscreep","warna":"IK05910,Grey","pcs":"63","tanggal_input":"2020-06-18","user":"Dena","keterangan":"Cutting Done"}]}

I already try to alert the data and it show :
{"hasil":[{"kode_list":"LPT20060001","tanggal":"2020-06-08","status_order":"Full order","buyer":"IK001,Ik Collection","nama_barang":"IK05900,Renata Blouse","jenis_kain":"Mosscreep","warna":"IK05910,Grey","pcs":"63","tanggal_input":"2020-06-18","user":"Dena","keterangan":"Cutting Done"}]}

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the variable type of `data` to loop through it. You can check the type of the variable by `console.log(typeof data)`. Following is the possible solution for your problem, see if this helps you.

```
success:function(data){
    
    console.log(typeof data);  // should be string
    
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    
    console.log(typeof data); // should be object
   
    $.each(data['hasil'], function(key, val){ 
        
         $.each(val, function(subkey, subval){
             
            console.log(subkey);
            console.log(subval);
    
            // all values are assigned to the elements with the same id as their keys(as your code suggests)
            $('#' + subkey).val('<value="' + subval + '">');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: try console.log(data);

Comment: You probably need to read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902504/why-js-variable-show-object-object-but-console-log-works/52902619

Comment: It works now, thanks for helping.
I need to learn more about javascript