# output returns as [object, Object]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a code that take user input and stores it in an object array. However it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. whenever I try to print out the array it just says [object, Object].
Thanks in advance!

```js
let addedProducts = [];
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let productName = document.getElementById("product-name").value;
let productAmount = document.getElementById("amount-stored").value;

const addProduct = () => {
  product = {
    name: productName,
    amount: productAmount
  }
  addedProducts.push(product.name);
  addedProducts.push(product.amount);
  document.forms[0].reset();
}

const showProducts = () => {
  output.innerHTML = addedProducts;

}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>ProductName</label>
  <input id="product-name" type="text"><br>
  <label>amount in store</label>
  <input id="amount-stored" type="text"><br>
  <input type="button" value="add product in array" onclick="addProduct()">
  <input type="button" value="show products in array" onclick="showProducts()">
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: What are you tring to achieve here? How do you want the output to be?

Comment: _“whenever I try to print out the array it just says [object, Object]”_ - that just means that you are trying to force an object into a string context. You need to access the individual array elements, or join them together to a string first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892465/what-does-object-object-mean-javascript/30632434

Comment: I wanted to output the data stored in the array.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: I believe the problem is that the input data isn't stored at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `productName` and `productAmount` are defined when your code is loaded, so they default to `""`.

When you click the buttons, the values have not been updated so you just add empty strings to `addedProducts`.

Try the following:

```
let addedProducts = [];
let output = document.getElementById("output");

const addProduct = () => {
  let productName = document.getElementById("product-name").value;
  let productAmount = document.getElementById("amount-stored").value;
  product = {
    name: productName,
    amount: productAmount
  }
  addedProducts.push(product.name);
  addedProducts.push(product.amount);
  document.forms[0].reset();
}

const showProducts = () => {
  output.innerHTML = addedProducts;
}
```

Comment: @KidRonee I updated the answer with a code sample. Please try that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you read values within `addProduct`:

```
const addProduct = () => {
  let productName = document.getElementById("product-name").value;
  let productAmount = document.getElementById("amount-stored").value;
  product = {
    name: productName,
    amount: productAmount
  }
  addedProducts.push(product);;
  document.forms[0].reset();
}

const showProducts = () => {
  output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(addedProducts, null, '\t');
}
```

```js
let addedProducts = [];
let output = document.getElementById("output");


const addProduct = () => {
  let productName = document.getElementById("product-name").value;
  let productAmount = document.getElementById("amount-stored").value;
  product = {
    name: productName,
    amount: productAmount
  }
  addedProducts.push(product);;
  document.forms[0].reset();
}

const showProducts = () => {
  output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(addedProducts, null, '\t');
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>ProductName</label>
  <input id="product-name" type="text"><br>
  <label>amount in store</label>
  <input id="amount-stored" type="text"><br>
  <input type="button" value="add product in array" onclick="addProduct()">
  <input type="button" value="show products in array" onclick="showProducts()">
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to print every element like:

```
const showProducts = () => {
        foreach(addedProducts as addedproduct)
            output.innerHTML =  output.innerHTML + addedproduct;
    }
```

either:

you have to write your code on event callback like `onChange()` method.

Comment: i didnt mean your product, what i was meaning was the foreach element. so i edit the answer