JSON.parse not parsing string of array of object
In my Node.js file route I am rendering an ejs file with variables passed as stringified array of object -
let scriptArray = [
  {
    charValue: 'a',
    encodedValueMain: 'g',
  },
  {
    charValue: 'b',
    encodedValueMain: 'o',
  },
  ]


router.route('/playground')
.get((req, res) =>{
    res.render('playground', {value: JSON.stringify(scriptArray)})
})

where scriptArray is a JSON object
Then, I embedded the value in a hidden input tag in the playground.ejs file -
<input type="hidden" id="test" value="<%= value %>">

and I tried to parse it in the JS script of this ejs file for further use -
(function () {
    let temp = document.getElementById('test');
    let script = JSON.parse(temp);
    console.log(script)
  })();

I was expecting the output to be an array of objects, exactly like how I assigned it in node.js file. but rather it gives me an error in the browser console -
VM600:1 Uncaught 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object HTM"... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at playground.js:5:19
    at playground.js:7:5
(anonymous) @   playground.js:5
(anonymous) @   playground.js:7

please help me solve this issue. Is there any other way I can access the node.js passed variables in my frontend JS file, without embedding it in a hidden input tag? If not, how do I solve this issue??
Thanks in advance.

In the error message you can see you are trying to parse the string [object HTM... instead of the actual string-ified object. The token o is just calling out the JSON.parse() fails on the "o" in "object". You're problem is that the value of the HTML input is not actually being populated with a string, but with "[object HTML]". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892465/what-does-object-object-mean-javascript

console.log(temp) will reveal a lot about the string you are trying to parse.

That's because you are passing an HTML-Element to the JSON.parse function.
Fix:
(function () {
    let temp = document.getElementById('test');
    let script = JSON.parse(temp.value); // <-- changed line
    console.log(script)
  })();

Also keep in mind that JSON has " as delimiters, so your value in
<input type="hidden" id="test" value="<%= value %>">

must be escaped for HTML. That might already be the case - depending on what you use to render...

Thanks for the solution. Is there any other way I can access my node.js variables in my frontend js file, without having it to embed in a hidden element in html?
